# Why was this question retagged?

Tags: support, tags

[Dapper .QueryAsync<long> fails with cast error only when async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584991/dapper-queryasynclong-fails-with-cast-error-only-when-async)

An editor removed the originally posted tags: `asynchronous` and `async-await`.

The description of `asynchronous` is:

> This covers the asynchronous programming support added to C# and VB in
>   VS2012. This includes the async and await keywords.

And `async-await`:

> This covers the asynchronous programming support added to C# and VB in
>   VS2012. This includes the async and await keywords.

In reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging, both tags seem sufficiently related to the question as to be the only tag for that question.

This is of no great concern, but still it me wonder if I misusing the tagging system, as this is not the first question of mine to be re-tagged. If not, are there re-tagging guidelines of greater detail than those in the above link?

Comment: You should ask the editor, not us. You can tag them explicitly in a comment (even if username auto-completion won't list their name). So using `@usr` in a comment will ping that editor (because they edited the post).

Comment: Neither tag-wiki nor excerpt for [tag:asynchronous] match your description. Other than that, I don't know. Pinged the editor to notify him.

Comment: Yelling for help in a crowded stadium can be troublesome, it doesn't scale well when everybody has to listen.  You surely ran into an expert on async/await that thought you'd be better helped by an expert on [dapper].  Which is quite likely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed those tags because they are visibly not related to the problem you are facing. Your problem is an exception deep in the bowels of Dapper. It is an invalid cast. This seems very unrelated to `async/await`.

We don't add tags for every syntactic feature that happens to be present in the question. Tags must be related to the problem.

Tags are there for discovery of questions and for clarification. None of these are supported by tagging `await`.

Comment: Fair enough. I figured async/await were at least borderline related to the problem since the difference between two results was the use of async. 
Now that you put it that way, I see that I was incorrect in my tagging. Thank you for the response.